# VB.NET Project Folder Question

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

So if I am working on a project in VB.net (really any visual studio project), I am able to create folders.  My project is getting rather unweildy (over 30 classes) and I think it would be beneficial to store for example data structure classes in a folder "ds" and user controls in a folder "uc".  Is this OK?  Will it affect the way I reference the classes?  Are the folders simply for my own use and structure or do they actually have some kind of impact on my project as a whole?

PS in case you are confused, I am referring to the structure shown in the "Solution Explorer".  Sorry if this is a dumb question or not clear, but I have never worked on a large project like this before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such thing as dumb questions. ;) You can do this, but do yourself a favor and keep your namespaces the same as your folder hierarchy or you can end up with a bird's nest pretty quickly. For example, if the project's default namespace is MyProject and the folder is Dc, those classes should be in

```
Namespace MyProject.Dc
```

*Edit: Just wrap your classes to mirror your folder structure like:*

```
Namespace MyProject.Ds
    Module MyModule

        Sub Main()
            'do stuff here
        End Sub

    End Module
End Namespace
```

Comment: What is the proper way to use a namespace in VB?  Do I just add
    $Namespace ds

    $End Namespace
to the beginning and end of each class?

Comment: Arg, I can never figure out how to format stuff on this website!

Comment: I edited for a more specific example. You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt9tafza.aspx). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Adding the folders will default the namespace of any newly added files into those folders to include the folder name. For example MyApp.UC or MyApp.DS.

Creating a folder and moving your user controls, data structures etc. shouldn't be a problem.

You can always test this on a new Test Project - that's my usual way :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use folders for everything. I do it all the time, you just need to include the folders name when accessing it.

[image]

So if I wanted to call something in the Exceptions folder, I would use Exceptions.DialogExceptionEdit, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new Folder shouldn't change anything in your project, if you are careful about the namespaces they are in and also being careful while referring to Class files using their path.